# PHP (Laravel) giving error when finding php_openssl.dll

Tags: php, laravel, openssl, php-extension

I'm trying to install Laravel, but when I do `php artisan serve`, it gives me an error that it couldn't find the extension `php_openssl.dll` on the `ext` folder. I looked it up, and it's there. The php.ini file is well (uncommented the line to install the openssl extension), but it still gives me this error.

Actually, when running the command, the Laravel server starts, but it gives me an error:
[image: Laravel error]

Don't know if it's related with the file, but I hope so :/

Comment: Does `phpinfo()` show anything strange or unexpected?

Comment: You could try to reinstall the plugin

Comment: is open ssl enabled thorough apache?

Comment: where should I write it? @apokryfos

Comment: Create a file like `info.php` with content `<?php phpinfo();` and put it in your http root (where your laravel index is, typically the public folder). Then run `localhost/info.php`. It should tell you where the "real" php.ini is in case you were editing the wrong one for example.

Comment: it shows me the path to the .ini file i edited @apokryfos

Comment: @Adrià  Two more questions: (1) does it show that openssl is enabled? (2) if you run `php-config --extension-dir` (should be in the php/bin directory) what does it say?

Comment: (1)Yes, it does
(2)Couldn't find it... (Couldn't even find the /bin)

Comment: Probably duplicates https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38582389/laravel-undefined-function-openssl-encrypt

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel undefined function openssl\_encrypt()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38582389/laravel-undefined-function-openssl-encrypt)