# Laravel undefined function openssl_encrypt()

Tags: php, apache, laravel

I use laravel5.1 and it works fine on php cli.
But i publish my porject to apache(version == 2.4), the problem happened.

> FatalErrorException in Encrypter.php line 67:
>   Call to undefined function openssl_encrypt()

Comment: Might be a configuration issue in Apache or `php.ini`, not sure though

Comment: You're missing the PHP openssl extension → http://php.net/manual/en/openssl.installation.php

Answer (score 27):

First make sure you installed the [openssl extension](http://php.net/manual/en/openssl.installation.php) (spotted by [deceze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/476/deceze)), then:

1. Go to your `php.ini` file
2. Remove the semicolon before `extension=php_openssl.dll`
3. Restart your Apache

I'm expecting this to be the problem.

Comment: in my particular case the `php_openssl.dll` extension was not being loaded because the PHP binaries directoy was not set in the system `PATH` environment variable

Answer (score 9):

I solved same issue by copying libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll from PHP root folder to Apache/bin folder and then restarted Apache.

Answer (score 7):

If you using the Wamp server then it's happens. In Xampp server there is no need to uncomment php_openssl.dll.

To solve this Remove the semicolon before

```
extension = php_openssl.dll
```

in php.ini

Answer (score 6):

as most point out, you need to uncomment openssl extension in php.ini.

I was struggling with the same too and i realized php is looking for extensions in **"c:\php"**, but mine was a xampp installation. 
Pointing **extension_dir** in php.ini to correct php extension path; in my case "c:\xampp\php.7\ext" solved the issue.

Hope that helps somebody.

Answer (score 3):

Follow the below steps:

- In PHP 7.4.3 duplicate **"php.ini-development"** file and rename it
  to **"php.ini"**
- Then, remove the semi-colons in front of **"extension=openssl"**,
  **"extension=mbstring"**, and **"extension_dir = ext"** inside the "php.ini" file.

This worked for me and I hope it helps someone else.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows
Open php.ini and change path where are locate php ext

extension_dir = "C:\php\ext"

Answer (score 0):

I am using wampserver and i had the same problem. Openssl was enabled in php.ini but there is another ini called ***phpForApache*** which has a line to enable openssl too. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using nginx, and my nginx installation contained a PHP folder, something like below:

```
C:\Users\myusername\Downloads\nginx\php\php.ini
```

I moved the nginx above to the root directory of `C:\` and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. Just run the composer update command from Laravel installation directory And 02. make sure extension=php_openssl.dll is enabled in php.ini
2. Restart Apache Server