# Getting Call to undefined function openssl_encrypt() on fresh install laravel on Windows

Tags: php, laravel

I'm getting this error message:

> FatalThrowableError in Encrypter.php line 73:
>   Call to undefined function openssl_encrypt()

I just installed Laravel with composer on xampp. I checked my `php.ini` 
and the `extension=php_openssl.dll` is enabled. I restarted Apache several time, cleared the cache but I still have this error. Any idea?

Comment: If you do a `phpinfo()`, is the extension enabled too? Had this kind of problems many times, after which it turned out Apache was loading a different php.ini than I thought it was.

Comment: Did you also installed the openssl extension? See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38582389/laravel-undefined-function-openssl-encrypt