# FatalThrowableError in Encrypter.php line 73: Call to undefined function openssl_encrypt()

Tags: laravel

I bought a script (radio web portal) which use Laravel framework but I have the following error :

```
FatalThrowableError in Encrypter.php line 73:
Call to undefined function openssl_encrypt()
in Encrypter.php line 73
at Encrypter->encrypt('msDJBCdI0hnJ95VuR6dnHo4jmZwo13AVVcb2FNEq') in 
EncryptCookies.php line 131
at EncryptCookies->encrypt(object(Response)) in EncryptCookies.php line 59
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php 
line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php 
line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php 
line 104
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 644
at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php 
line 618
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 596
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 267
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request)) in 
Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Debugbar.php 
line 51
at Debugbar->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 
137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php 
line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in 
CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 46
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in 
Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php 
line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php 
line 104
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 149
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 116
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 53
in Encrypter.php line 73
at Encrypter->encrypt('a:5:
```

{s:6:"_token";s:40:"msDJBCdI0hnJ95VuR6dnHo4jmZwo13AVVcb2FNEq";s:9:"_previous";a:1:{s:3:"url";s:47:"http://localhost/sito2/radiowebportal/index.php";}s:22:"PHPDEBUGBAR_STACK_DATA";a:0:{}s:9:"_sf2_meta";a:3:{s:1:"u";i:1526184338;s:1:"c";i:1526184338;s:1:"l";s:1:"0";}s:6:"_flash";a:2:{s:3:"old";a:0:{}s:3:"new";a:0:{}}}') in EncryptedStore.php line 57
at EncryptedStore->prepareForStorage('a:5:{s:6:"_token";s:40:"msDJBCdI0hnJ95VuR6dnHo4jmZwo13AVVcb2FNEq";s:9:"_previous";a:1:{s:3:"url";s:47:"http://localhost/sito2/radiowebportal/index.php";}s:22:"PHPDEBUGBAR_STACK_DATA";a:0:{}s:9:"_sf2_meta";a:3:{s:1:"u";i:1526184338;s:1:"c";i:1526184338;s:1:"l";s:1:"0";}s:6:"_flash";a:2:{s:3:"old";a:0:{}s:3:"new";a:0:{}}}') in Store.php line 262
at Store->save() in StartSession.php line 88
at StartSession->terminate(object(Request), object(Response)) in Kernel.php line 176
at Kernel->terminate(object(Request), object(Response)) in index.php line 58

Comment: The answer is in your question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel undefined function openssl\_encrypt()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38582389/laravel-undefined-function-openssl-encrypt)

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you installed the openssl extension (spotted by deceze), then:

Go to your php.ini file
Remove the semicolon before extension=php_openssl.dll
Restart your Apache
I'm expecting this to be the problem.